# difference between using sudo su - versus setting ALL in sudoer

Tags: sudo

I have an account which needs to execute all commands :

should i provide su - command permission for the account or set "ALL" permissions on command.

su - can elevate as root and run any command; ALL permits any command execution including root.
what is benefit from a security standpoint of using one over the other for my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience:

- `su -`:

  Environment of root replaces whatever you were using before.
  The root password must be used.
- `sudo /bin/bash`:

  Basically uses your environment augmented a bit by sudo.
  Specify USER password and does not use the root password.

Both put a log entry that one elevated privs by either method.

The difference between the two is having to give away the root password.
Another difference is the environment setup.